# Why does "category:social" with in GMail UI search, but does not work in GmailApp.search("category:social", 0, 500);

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

So putting "category:social" in the GMail UI correctly returns email in the Social tab.

Putting `const threads = GmailApp.search("category:social", 0, 500);` returns nothing.

The social categorized emails DO appear under `const threads = GmailApp.search("category:updates", 0, 500);`

Am I not understanding how GMail uses the Category label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The GMAIL UI and Apps Script searches return exactly the same results

You can test again by e.g. modifying your code as following and view the logs:

```
function test(){
  const threads = GmailApp.search("category:social", 0, 500); 
  threads.forEach(function(thread){
  console.log(thread.getFirstMessageSubject())
  })
}
```

Btw., the category label can be adjusted by you as desired - either from the Gmail UI or Gmail API

You can view /edit your labels when opening an email and clicking on the label icon:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I found a bug elsewhere that was affecting the start index number.

Comment: Worth noting that the reason this behavior existed was `search(query, start, max)` will return an empty array if the number of remaining messages in the requested batch (`max`) is less than the `start` index number. So in the example below if there are 9 messages remaining and all meet the search criteria the return will be null.

Google Documentation:
`// Find starred messages with subject IMPORTANT and return second batch of 10.
// Assumes there are at least 11 of them, otherwise this will return an empty array.
var threads = GmailApp.search('is:starred subject:"IMPORTANT"', 10, 10);`